# Joomla Upgrade Database Error from v3.1.1 to 3.1.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.1

I have been upgrade joomla from 3.1.1 to 3.1.5 site locally. But both frontend & backend is broken. Fronend url is redirecting to www.mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1799. The sql upgrade did not pass. I tried to apply database fix option but even like that did not get it to work in my case. Actually I need to upgrade joomla to latest version. Checked in joomla forums, but couldn't be able to solve this issue.

Got the following error when checked the Extension > Database option.

```
Database schema version (3.1.1) does not match CMS version (3.1.5).
Database update version (3.2.7) does not match CMS version (3.1.5).
Table 'j25_associations' does not have column 'id' with type 'INT(11)'. (From file 3.0.3.sql.)
Table 'j25_contentitem_tag_map' does not exist. (From file 3.1.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_tags' does not exist. (From file 3.1.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_ucm_base' does not exist. (From file 3.1.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_ucm_content' does not exist. (From file 3.1.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_modules' does not have column 'asset_id'. (From file 3.2.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_postinstall_messages' does not exist. (From file 3.2.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_ucm_history' does not exist. (From file 3.2.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_users' does not have column 'otpKey'. (From file 3.2.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_users' does not have column 'otep'. (From file 3.2.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_user_keys' does not exist. (From file 3.2.0.sql.)
Table 'j25_update_sites' does not have column 'extra_query'. (From file 3.2.2-2013-12-22.sql.)
Table 'j25_updates' does not have column 'extra_query'. (From file 3.2.2-2013-12-22.sql.)
Table 'j25_updates' does not have column 'version' with type 'varchar(32)'. (From file 3.2.2-2014-01-18.sql.)
```

Getting the following error when clicked on Fix button:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method InstallerControllerDatabase::checkToken() in /home/myserver/public_html/checker/administrator/components/com_installer/controllers/database.php on line 28
```

How could I fix my broken tables? Any help would be really appreciated. Sitting with this for one week, still not able to solve this issue.

versions:
PHP 5.6.38-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.36-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

In local I am using mariaDb and in live I am using mysql. 
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.36-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Will this cause an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encountered the same issue few months back. You are getting the database error because of not discovering the new components. Please do the following and discover components.

Please revert back the Joomla Version. (3.1.1)

Go to Admin Area > Extensions > Manage > Discover.

Click on Discover Button.

There you will see newly Discovered items.
Click and install those items.

Then after clearing cache, click on Database Option and Try Fix Button.

After that do upgrade.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother!

Answer (score 0):

Your update may be incomplete. Update the file directly on your root and replace it with the previous Joomla!
To download the update file from version 3.1.1 to 3.1.5, go to the link below and download the update file in zip format.

https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3/3-1-5

Please download this item "Joomla! 3.1.x to 3.1.5 Patch Package (.zip)"

Comment: I did manual update exactly as what you said. But not sure why this error is throwing.